# What are good resources to learn about VAR models?

Tags: time-series, self-study, references, vector-autoregression

I am looking for websites, books, lecture notes, or research papers to learn about VARs. At the moment I have no knowledge of them.

I would greatly appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most comprehensive texts I know of on the subject would be [Lutkehpohl](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540262393) (2010) or [Tsay](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118617908) (2015). The latter has its own R package (MTS) and several programming exercises. If you want something that covers the univariate case first then motivates the VAR, there's always [Hamilton](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/5386.html) (1994).